# How to avoid clicking push Button twice in Qt

Tags: qt, button

In my Qt application, I have a push button to launch a job which takes ~10s to complete. I notice that during the 10s period after clicking the button, if I click in the button area again, it is still taken as a click and the job will be launched again as soon as it is concluded from the first click.

Is this expected? What can I do to avoid the button click until the job from the first click is concluded? Thanks.

Comment: You have to disable your button in the corresponding slot and enable it again when associated job is done. This first is easy. For the second phase you need to know when jobs are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After poking on it, I think the "QCoreApplication::processEvents()" does the trick. Here is what I find out, also as a conclusion to the subject:

=========================

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QDateTime dateTime;
    qDebug()<<"Btn2-Time#1:"<<dateTime.currentDateTime().toString("[yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss] ");
    QThread::sleep(10);
    qDebug()<<"Btn2-Time#2:"<<dateTime.currentDateTime().toString("[yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss] ");
}
```

Originally my code is like above, and as I click the button and click again during the 10s sleep time, I get this and notice the 2nd run start immediately after the 1st run concluded.

```
Btn2-Time#1: "[20170731 16:07:39] "
Btn2-Time#2: "[20170731 16:07:49] "
Btn2-Time#1: "[20170731 16:07:49] "
Btn2-Time#2: "[20170731 16:07:59] "
```

=========================

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QDateTime dateTime;
    ui->pushButton->setEnabled(false);

    qDebug()<<"Btn1-Time#1:"<<dateTime.currentDateTime().toString("[yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss] ");
    QThread::sleep(10);
    qDebug()<<"Btn1-Time#2:"<<dateTime.currentDateTime().toString("[yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss] ");
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    ui->pushButton->setEnabled(true);
```

}

Following one of the comment, I added the disable and QCoreApplication::processEvents(); as above, now the same operation will not trigger the 2nd run, because the 2nd click is processed before the button is reset to enable.

```
Btn1-Time#1: "[20170731 16:07:24] "
Btn1-Time#2: "[20170731 16:07:34] "
```

=========================

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    QDateTime dateTime;
    ui->pushButton_3->setEnabled(false);

    qDebug()<<"Btn3-Time#1:"<<dateTime.currentDateTime().toString("[yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss] ");;
    QThread::sleep(10);
    qDebug()<<"Btn3-Time#2:"<<dateTime.currentDateTime().toString("[yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss] ");
    //QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    ui->pushButton_3->setEnabled(true);
}
```

Commenting out the QCoreApplication::processEvents();, it processes the 2nd click as original, so just disabling the button isn't the solution, and the QCoreApplication::processEvents(); does the trick!

```
Btn3-Time#1: "[20170731 16:08:00] "
Btn3-Time#2: "[20170731 16:08:10] "
Btn3-Time#1: "[20170731 16:08:10] "
Btn3-Time#2: "[20170731 16:08:20] "
```

=========================

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I would disable the button until the job is completed and add a label (or GIF animation) to indicate the "work in progress". This is better for the user, as he sees that the button is disabled --> i.e. he has a "feedback" from your system. Then when the process is finished you emit a "finished" signal [Signals and Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html), that is connected to an "enableButtons" slot --> i.e. After finishing the process you re-enalbe the button.

```
void Process(){
 ui->yourButton->setEnabled(false);
/* Maybe play loading gif animation etc*/
/* Do your work here */
emit ProcessFinished();
}
```

Comment: I think this should work. However the other way in one of the comments of adding "QCoreApplication::processEvents()" seems to be simpler...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "setEnabled" and setDisabled" methods to deactivate the button when the job is exectued and then add a callback to activate the button when the job is complete.

Read the documentation for setEnabled here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enabled-prop

Comment: what do you mean by add a callback to activate the button? I tried to place setEnabled(false) at the beginning of the slot function and then setEnabled(true) at the end of the slot function, it makes no difference. I think the second click is considered click after the job is concluded and at that poin the button is enabled, the job is launched again...

Comment: If the button is disabled, the "clicked" event should be cancelled. The callback would be any call to the button's setEnabled() method.

Comment: @YeP If during the task execution the event loop is not executed, all input events will only be processed after the task is done. You could call `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` during the task, in particular when you expect the UI to change (e.g after enabling/disabling a button). Or you could move the task to another thread so that the task do not impacts the UI event loop (see QThread, QThreadPool and QtConcurrent).